# any simple way to OCR an image?

Tags: php, python, ocr

It basically only uses the font Times New Roman and is a small rectangle (220x86). Text is uniform, same size, no strange characters, AZaz09, eight different colors (one per line).

is there any easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The best Open Source OCR is [Tesseract](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/).  It is trainable,  so you can target times new roman,  although it already comes with training for similar text.   You can use it with python by using `os.popen()`

Comment: Im not too good with the whole linux thing (server is Openbsd 4.something), how do I use apt-get? (in readme it says to apt-get some packages and the command isn't found)

Comment: @pdx apt-get is dead simple to use,  its far easier to install stuff than windows.  If you can't use apt your probably terrified by the CLI,  so try using synaptic.

Comment: `apt-get install tesseract-ocr`

Comment: sorry about slow time, forgot ot check SO. Its openbsd, apt-get just says bash command not found, how do i install it?

Comment: @pdx apt is debian/ubuntu,  with other *nix it is still pretty simple just build from source.